# How to Hide Android Launcher Icon at Runtime while the App keeps being Upgradable

Tags: android, icons, runtime, hide, launcher

I have seen in other answers this code:

```
PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager(); 
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

This code indeed works, but if you try to reinstall or upgrade the app you can't start the activity that is disabled.

Is there any other way to hide the icon at runtime without losing the ability of reinstalling and upgrading?

Does anyone know?

Comment: Looking for the same solution

Answer (score 0):

Problems you encounter on install is because your only exported component (activity marked with main and launcher) is disabled by above code. You can add some other exported component to get back into the app (for example register broadcast receiver for GCM or SMS receive). Similar approach needs to be done to re-enable updating from play store (and even installing from eclipse). Unfortunately I am not certain what component needs to be added for those two. 
Workaraound: You could send GCM broadcast to users and re-enable the launcher component before pushing the update but I think there are probably better ways.